# Is this a good solution for R#'s complaint about loss of precision?

Tags: c#, double, resharper, mathematical-optimization, epsilon

There was some code in my project that compared two double values to see if their difference exceeded 0, such as:

```
if (totValue != 1.0)
```

Resharper complained about this, suggesting I should use "EPSILON" and added just such a constant to the code (when invited to do so). However, it does not create the constant itself or suggest what value it should be. Is this a good solution:

```
const double EPSILON = double.Epsilon; // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx
. . .
if (Math.Abs(totValue - 1.0) > EPSILON)
    compValue = Convert.ToString(totValue*Convert.ToDouble(compValue));
```

?

### UPDATE

I changed it to this:

```
const double EPSILON = 0.001;
```

...thinking that's probably both large and small enough to work for typical double vals (not scientific stuff, just "I have 2.5 of these," etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a sensible value for your epsilon.  The code you have is no different than a straight equality check.

`double.Epsilon` is the smallest possible difference that there can be between any two doubles.  There is no way for any two doubles to be closer to each other than by being `double.Epsilon` apart, so the only way for this check to be true is for them to be *exactly* equal.

As for what epsilon value you should actually use, that simply depends, which is why one isn't automatically generated for you.  It all depends on what types of operations you're doing to the data (which affects the possible deviation from the "true value") along with how much precision actually care about in your application (and of course if the precision that you care about is greater than your margin of error, you have a problem).  Your epsilon needs to be some precision value greater than (or equal to) the precision you need, while being less than the possible margin of error of all operations performed on either numeric value.

Comment: It's not about 'how much you care about', it is rather 'how much error do you expect'. Setting the epsilon to how much you care about can hide errors.

Comment: @alzaimar The epsilon needs to be *between the two*, as I have said in my answer.  You cannot *just* account for one or the other.  If there is no space between the two, which is to say that your margin of error is greater than your required precision, then the problem is insolvable, and you'll either need to reduce your margin of error or live with decreased precision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But even better is to not use floating point. Use `decimal` instad.

However, if, for some reason, you have to stick to `double` never compare directly, that means, never rely on e.g. `a-b == 0` with (`a` and `b` being some `double` values which are meant to be equal).

Floating point arithmetic is fast, but not precise, and taken that into account, R# is correct.

Comment: The epsilon value that he is using is *not* appropriate, for reasons described in my answer.

Comment: Absolute correct. I was focusing on the floating point issue.